# how to set region of interest?

Tags: video, multimedia, roi

Right now I am trying to make a movie, whose size is 640 x 480(4:3 aspect ratio).And I am editing a composition whose size is, 1024x1024, 1k resolution, and I want to make a proxy of this 1k compositon, but I want to make the proxy size 640 x 480. The reason why I am editing 1k compositon is because it's easier to make a movie if there is larger space in compositon.

So I need to use region of interest to crop the original 1k composition, but it's time-consuming to set the region of interest manually. Do you know how to make the region of interest precisely? I thought I put the 1k compositon into 640x480 compositon and make a proxy movie from it, but it means I need to make a lot more compositons to make proxy. It will make my project panel messy...

Answer (score 0):

There are both open-source and closed-source solutions to this type of problem.

For an open-source solution, check out the [crop filter from AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/197f820b-f5d0-57cb-a509-5dbcacdda446.htm):

```
// create filter
Crop filter = new Crop( new Rectangle( 75, 75, 320, 240 ) );
// apply the filter
Bitmap newImage = filter.Apply( image );
```

You could also check out libraries such as LEADTOOLS, which has a similar still image crop filter:

```
// create filter
CropCommand command = new CropCommand(new LeadRect(100, 100, image.Width - 100, image.Height - 100));
// Crop 100 pixels from each side of the image
command.Run(image);
```

If you're editing with a framework like DirectShow, you could check out an open source video crop filters such as the one at http://videoprocessing.sourceforge.net/#crop or the LEAD Video Crop Filter.

Disclaimer: My employer is LEAD Technologies, Inc.